# How to add a TrueType Font to Ghostscript

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, ghostscript

It's my first time trying to do anything with Ghostscript (GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)).  I'm trying to convert an `.abc` music file into a PDF, but I want to use a custom Olde English font that I have installed for the titles.  The font is originally located at `~/.local/share/fonts/Olde English Regular.ttf`.  Since that isn't one of the paths I see in `gs -h`, I made a copy in `/usr/share/fonts` and added a line like this to my fontmap:

```
/OldeEnglish-Regular (Olde English Regular.ttf) ;
```

But when I try to open the file, I get a few errors like this and Courier is substituted.

```
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.55.0/Resource/Font//usr/share/ghostscri.
Can't find (or can't open) font file OldeEnglish-Regular,.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for OldeEnglish-Regular,.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I copied that directly from the log and I didn't change any settings other than adding that one line to the end of the Fontmap file.  I already tried removing the spaces in the file name, and that didn't seem to help so I reverted it.

Comment: Rather than adding a symbolic link or whatever, put the full path to the font in the fontmap entry.